# Impute Missing Values for Numerical and Categorical, and center and scale the categorical values with exceptions in R

Tags: r, data-modeling, prediction, missing-data, training-data

I would like to impute median for numerical missing values and mode for categorical missing values
and then convert all the categorical values into dummies, center and scale them.
However, I do not want to convert the customer IDs, nor to center and scale them.
Could you help me to fix my code?

```
library(recipes)
train.recipe <- recipe(y ~., data = trainingdata) %>%
  step_medianimpute(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_modeimpute(all_nominal())
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes(), - trainingdata$Customer_ID) %>%
    step_center(all_predictors(), -trainingdata$Customer_ID) %>%
    step_scale(all_predictors(), -trainingdata$Customer_ID)

train.recipe %>%
  prep() %>%
  bake(., data.clean) %>%
  glimpse()
```

Comment: Could you provide some data?

Comment: Customer_ID   Monthly_Revenue  Monthly_Minutes 
 100072 :   1   Min.   :  0.00   Min.   :   0.0  
 100403 :   1   Median : 47.78   Median : 364.0  
 100915 :   1   Mean   : 57.92   Mean   : 522.5  
 (Other):9594                                    
 Monthly_Rec_Charge Director_Assisted_Calls Overage_Minutes  
 Min.   :  0.00     Min.   : 0.0000         Min.   :   0.00  
 Median : 45.00     Median : 0.2500         Median :   3.00  
 Mean   : 46.47     Mean   : 0.8954         Mean   :  38.75

Comment: @TonyFlager do you care about how this is achieved? Because there are dozens of answers from converting customer id's to rownames to simply using functions / workflows that allow you to more explicitly name the columns for transformation. So do you need a solution using ```recipes``` and ```step_dummy()```?

Comment: @Fnguyen no I don't care. I just want to make sure that the all the values are normalized and standardized, except the customer ID. Could you help me? Just give me the simplest way to do it, as I am quite new in R.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data frame and assuming that customer id is the only variable you do not want to transform you can simply first transform the ids to rownames before transforming:

```
df %>%
  column_to_rownames("id") # to convert column to rownames

df %>%
  rownames_to_column("id") # to revert that
```

**To do this the customer ids need to be unique!**